# How to get cordinates by clicking on a google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to google maps and want to use google map javascript API to display houses as markers. I want a person to be able to click on the map to place a marker, which can be clicked again to be removed or dragged to another location on the map. Then, I want the script to get the cordinates(lat and long) so that I can ad it to a database table. Any idea how I should do this? I'm using PHP in codeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be to check out the reference manual: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html

If you look at map there you can see that it has an event called "click". What you do is after your map has been initialized you make an eventlistener, that listens to the click event. When that occurs you then place a marker on that location, and add an eventlistener on that marker for the click event if you want to remove it, or make it draggable if you want to drag it.

Remember to store your markers in an array if you ever want to use the information they are holding again.

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party. Please find below code snipet.

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
        var marker;
        map.addListener('click', function(e) {
          
          if(marker){

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng());
            marker.setPosition(latlng);
          }else{
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: {lat : e.latLng.lat(), lng : e.latLng.lng()},
                  map: map
                })
          }

          alert("lat : "+e.latLng.lat()+ "; lng : "+e.latLng.lng())

          });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDNPpCPQOwkMotaDj0IgHQ7HDAE8cz6-4U&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```